# Qualified solution of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

When solving a PDE with respect to a function $u$, we typically claim $u:U\to R$ in advance, where $U$ is an open set of $R^n$. But I find that sometimes the solution $u$ could have undefined points in $U$, such as $u=\log|x|$ at $x=0$. Is it still a qualified solution in the domain $U$? Besides, when we talk about the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(U)$, does the space also include the functions possibly with undefined points?